# mysql with inner query

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores the answer from a survey and im trying to query mysql to tell me if a survey was answered by someone where the answer field = 16 or 20

I have the following for a mysql statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT(submissionID) as submissionID FROM answer 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM answer
    WHERE submissionID = submissionID AND (answer = '16' OR answer = '20')

)
```

EDIT HERE

Sorry I dont think I said my question right so here is my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `answer` (
  `aID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qtID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer` text NOT NULL,
  `userIP` text NOT NULL,
  `submissionID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`aID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=422 ;
```

1. `aID` is the unique id for every answer given
2. `sID` is the survey id (cause I may have more than one survey)
3. `qtID` is the questionsID value
4. `answer` is the answer the user gave this the `qtID` of this survey
5. `userIP` is self explainable
6. `submissionID` is the ID a gave each submission

so I know in this table there are 5 unique submissionID's but there is only one `submssionID` the answer field = `16` and `20`

Comment: no its just return all the unique submissionID's but i only want the submissionID's where the answer has a value of 16 and 20 both

Comment: "but there is only one submssionID the answer field = 16 and 20" < question is still not clear. Are you looking for some user that filled out the same survey twice and gave two different answers to one particular question? Are you looking for surveys that have 16 as answer to one particular question and 20 to another question? Or maybe there can be multiple qtID per sID and you're looking for submissions that have one row with 16 and one row with 20 for the same qtID and sID?

Comment: "I know in this table there are 5 unique submissionID" you could consider posting the data and also give a sample of the desired result of the query you want to write.

Answer (score 1):

I think your query is overly complex, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT submissionID FROM answer 
WHERE answer IN ('16', '20');
```

Comment: Thanks this didnt work though.... there are 5 unique submissions in this table and i know only one has both 16 and 20 with it.  i ran your query and it returned all by submissionID's and the query im looking for should only return on the one submissionID has a record with answer = 16 and a record with answer = 20.

Comment: @user875293 That isn't what your query above was trying to do, it was looking for one that was 16 OR 20. If you want a match with 16 AND 20 you need to give more information about your table because a column can't have 16 and 20 in it.

Answer (score 0):

"Whats my malfunction here ?"

The condition that correlates the subquery to the outer query:

```
submissionID = submissionID
```

is always true. I don't think you actually need it anyway, why not write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT submissionID 
FROM answer 
WHERE answer = '16' OR answer = '20'
```

However, I get the feeling you're not giving us all the information. For instance, I don't see anything in your original query to restrict to answers to a particular question. That's possible of course if the survey has just one question, but I get the feeling that's not what you meant. Elaborate...

Comment: I was just about to answer 100% the same :).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need an alias for the answer table in one or the other from clauses.  Like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT(submissionID) as submissionID FROM answer a 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM answer
    WHERE submissionID = a.submissionID AND (answer = '16' OR answer = '20')

)
```

Comment: Well, but then why have a subquery at all? You could just as well applied the IN clause in the WHERE of the outer query and leave out the subquery.

Comment: You are quite correct.  I was just making the minimal changes to his query to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your original query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(submissionID) as submissionID FROM answer 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM answer
    WHERE submissionID = submissionID AND (answer = '16' OR answer = '20')

)
```

You should add an alias to the tables to correlate them

```
SELECT DISTINCT(submissionID) as submissionID FROM answer B
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM answer A
    WHERE A,submissionID = B.submissionID AND (answer = '16' OR answer = '20')

)
```